# How can I select the first paragraph in this code?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Hi everyone,

I am new to coding and have a really simple question that I can't figure out. In the following code below, how can I select the first paragraph but NOT the second in CSS? I want to make some manipulation to the first pargraph only! I've tried nth-child(1) but it's not working. Please help!

```
<div class="about" id="about">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Who Am I?</h1>
            <img src="images/MyFace.jpg">
            <p>paragraph1</p>
            <p>paragraph 2!</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS selector for first element with class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class)

Comment: @TylerH: But this has nothing to do with classes.

Comment: I'm puzzled as to why you changed the accepted answer to the one that claims three solutions to work, two of which you yourself confirmed did not work after having tried them, and the third of which was already provided earlier in the answer you originally accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the CSS `first-of-type` selector. The below CSS will select only the first instance of element type `p` within the element with class `container`.

```
.container > p:first-of-type{ /* css */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below Code there are 3 way to select first element:

**Solution 1:**

```
.container p:first-child { /* your CSS */ }
```

**Solution 2:**

```
.container p:first-of-type { /* your CSS */ }
```

**Solution 3:**

```
.container p:nth-child(1) { /* your CSS */ }
```

Comment: You obviously did not read the question or the answer that was provided more than 2 hours ago.